# Spring boot thin jar gradle config

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, intellij-14

I have a Java app written using Idea which includes several JARs by gradle (all dependencies are below). I need to build a thin JAR from that (i.e. leave most of the libraries used alone in /libs folder). But I can only run my app via java -jar if it is a fat jar (i.e. includes all jars inside itself). If I use simple 'jar' gradle task, it builds my thin jar fine but I can not execute it because it can not find any of needed libraries (i.e. spring-boot-* etc).

Could you please let me know what exactly should I write in my task to create a jar which will take into account the libraries are inside /libs folder relative to the jar.

So my dependencies section is:

```
dependencies {

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.8.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.8.Final")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.4.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.2.RELEASE")
    compile('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10')
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.9")
    compile("com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.5")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:4.3.7.Final")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0")
    compile("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:2.1.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0")
}
```

Task which copies all needed jars to the lib subfolder:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/libs/lib"
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

Task which builds jar (which does not start)

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'MyApp',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Start-Class': 'my.pkg.Application',
                'Main-Class': 'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher'
    }
    baseName = 'MyApp'
    version =  '1.6'
}
```

And a task which builds fat jar (which runs great)

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'MyApp',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'my.pkg.Application'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-fat'

    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }

    with jar
}
```

Comment: Does the 'application' plugin do what you want? http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. What are you trying to achieve? Run a fat jar? Or run a thin jar with libs passed as classpath?

Comment: I want this one: run a thin jar with libs passed as classpath

Comment: Did you solve the issue?